# Group by Expression

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my sqlfiddler bech;
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d859

```
Grades:

SID CID GRADE
--------------
S1  C1  50
S1  C2  85
S1  C3  60
S1  C4  90
S1  C5  50
S2  C1  30
S2  C2  40
S3  C2  85
S4  C2  80
S4  C4  75
S4  C5  60
```

We have Grades table,
SID = Student_ID
CID = Course_ID

We want to get SID of student who gets the highest grade from the course ‘C1’.

This is my solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT SID
FROM GRADES
WHERE GRADE =
    (SELECT max(GRADE)
     FROM GRADES
     GROUP BY CID HAVING CID = 'C1')
```

it works wrong in my opinion, how can i fix it?

Comment: "it works wrong in my opinion." But does it work?

Comment: Do you need the highest grade students or a number of students (like top 10) with top grades? How do you want it to works? What is correct output?

Comment: Need only highest grade student from C1 course

Comment: it works :) out of exception

Comment: Yes, it works wrong because you are getting students that never take the course.  Try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must filter the appropriate course date, order them by grade desc and get first row.

```
SELECT
  SID
FROM grades
WHERE CID = 'C1'
ORDER BY GRADE DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

or use this:

```
SELECT
  SID
FROM grades G1
WHERE CID = 'C1'
 AND GRADE = (SELECT MAX(GRADE) FROM grades G2 WHERE G2.CID = G1.CID)
```

*UPDATE*

The above query works for  SQL Server also.

but you can use this also:

```
SELECT TOP 1
  SID
FROM grades
WHERE CID = 'C1'
ORDER BY GRADE DESC
```

if there are more than one student with maximum grade in course and you want all them, you can use this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES
  SID
FROM grades
WHERE CID = 'C1'
ORDER BY GRADE DESC
```

**FOR Marcus Adams**

***Tested on:***

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (CTP2) - 12.0.1524.0 (X64) 
    Oct  3 2013 19:00:26 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: )
```

```
--SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
SELECT
  SID
FROM grades G1
WHERE CID = 'C1'
 AND GRADE = (SELECT MAX(GRADE) FROM grades G2 WHERE G2.CID = G1.CID)
```

```
(1 row(s) affected)

StmtText
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([Expr1002]=[Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[GRADE] as [G1].[GRADE]))
       |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1002]=MAX([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[GRADE] as [G2].[GRADE])))
       |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[PK__GRADES__4606D4B55925FD88] AS [G2]), WHERE:([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[CID] as [G2].[CID]='C1'))
       |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[PK__GRADES__4606D4B55925FD88] AS [G1]), WHERE:([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[CID] as [G1].[CID]='C1'))

(4 row(s) affected)
```

```
--SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON
SELECT
  SID
FROM grades G1
WHERE CID = 'C1'
 AND GRADE = (SELECT MAX(GRADE) FROM grades G2 WHERE G2.CID = 'C1')
```

```
(1 row(s) affected)

StmtText
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, WHERE:([Expr1002]=[Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[GRADE] as [G1].[GRADE]))
       |--Stream Aggregate(DEFINE:([Expr1002]=MAX([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[GRADE] as [G2].[GRADE])))
       |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[PK__GRADES__4606D4B55925FD88] AS [G2]), WHERE:([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[CID] as [G2].[CID]='C1'))
       |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[PK__GRADES__4606D4B55925FD88] AS [G1]), WHERE:([Test].[dbo].[GRADES].[CID] as [G1].[CID]='C1'))

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: what if there are morethan one students who have same grade as highest  grade score in C1 course

Comment: @DjMix Because your workbench created in MS SQL SERVER. Do you use MS SQL SERVER?

Comment: Consider replacing the `WHERE G2.CID = G1.CID` in your subquery with a literal value such as `WHERE G2.CID = 'C1'`. On MySQL at least, it will improve performance as it will turn the subquery from correlated (dependent) to non-correlated (it will run the subquery just once instead of for reach row).

Comment: @MarcusAdams, I think optimizer will generate equivalent plans for both.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, I tested this before I commented. It did not on v5.1.65, though it may be version dependent.

Comment: @MarcusAdams Added plans for both queries. The OP about MS SQL Server.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, as you know, originally, this question was for MySQL. I specifically mentioned MySQL in my comment.

Comment: @MarcusAdams, This optimization is obvious. If MySQL doesn't do it. That its bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong, because you select all student who got the same grade as the highest grade from the selected course. 
You would want only the students that actually did that course. For that, you need to add the selection for the course to the main query as well, not only the subquery.

You can write it like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  g.SID
FROM
  GRADES g
WHERE
  g.CID = 'C5' AND
  g.GRADE = (SELECT max(g1.GRADE)
     FROM GRADES g1
     WHERE g1.CID = g.CID)
```

This will return all students who have the highest grade. This can be multiple students if they got the same grade, but that seems logical if you have query like this. If you don't want that, you can Hamlet Hakobyan's answer, which will give you either one of the students who share the highest grade.

Note, I've added `DISTINCT` only because you've got double data in your example. Currently, Student S1 had two times the same highest grade, which is why it appears twice if you don't add DISTINCT.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9d859/35

Comment: How is this better than the original?

Comment: your answer is similar to mine, this query made group for C1 and get highest grade, and call SID with this grade, if there is similar grade, this query fail, Am i wrong? this is similar to my problem :)

Comment: Please try your query with 'C5', you will understand the point

Comment: if there are two students with same grade, the information (highest grade from C1 course) is gone

Comment: Oops. I see. Improved query added to answer.